# Should the system be an actor in Use case diagram of a social network app

Tags: uml, diagram, use-case

i was wondering if the system should be included as an actor in my use case diagram , my app is about a **social network** for developers, so the system is prompted to generate notifications to send to the user who gets a new friend request, and also the system send a notification to a user when he receieves a chat message ... does the system plays the role of an actor or not???
thank you in advance

Comment: what is the system ? if it is your app or a sub part of it then the answer is not, the actors are out of the system you model. Note also a notification is not sent to a user but to the application used by the user

Comment: yeah actually i though of the app as the system, and you're answer makes sens for me ,the actors must be exterior to the system, thank you very much sir

Answer (score 1):

No. The system is actually the *system under consideration*. It's not an actor but defines the border for actors. That's why you see a boundary grouping use cases and the actors outside that border attached to the use cases inside.

p. 637 of UML 2.5:

> UseCases are a means to capture the requirements of systems, i.e., what systems are supposed to do. The key concepts specified in this clause are Actors, UseCases, and subjects. Each UseCase’s subject represents a system under consideration to which the UseCase applies. Users and any other systems that may interact with a subject are represented as Actors.